# changin android:usesCleartextTraffic to false

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to change android:usesCleartextTraffic on androidmanifest, from true to false, because audit asked for it for security reasons, the problem is that when i do this the net error posup

Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@usesCleartextTraffic value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:7-43
is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:20:7-43 value=(flase).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-118 to override.

and i REALLY, need to do this any help would be apreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So simply resolve the issue by adding tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic" to your application tag

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic">
 
 //...

</application>
```

Comment: but that way, `android:usesCleartextTraffic` ain't still true?

Comment: This did the trick for me! This code goes in the debug/AndroidManifest.xml... In the main/AndroidManifest.xml the property keeps false.